# How to wait for a certain time, like midnight, before proceeding

Tags: ruby

We are trying to get a test to wait until exactly midnight before proceeding.

Currently it checks every second for midnight, which fills the console with a bunch of "waiting for midnight" messages.

Is there a way to have it just check the time then wait until midnight?

```
def wait_if_almost_midnight max_minutes_needed, utc: false
    seconds_waited = 0
    now = utc ? Time.now.utc : DateTime.now
    now_hour = now.strftime('%k').to_i
    now_minute = now.strftime('%M').to_i
    while now_hour == 23 && max_minutes_needed > (59 - now_minute)
      sleep 1
      seconds_waited += 1
       p "Waiting for midnight, seconds: #{seconds_waited}"
       now_hour = now.strftime('%k').to_i
      now_minute = now.strftime('%M').to_i
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Remove Call to Kernel#p

To answer your actual question, just remove the Kernel#p call to stop filling up your console:

```
# This is what's printing to your console.
p "Waiting for midnight, seconds: #{seconds_waited}"
```

However, sleep loops like this are not really very efficient. You might be better off using cron to kick of a process at midnight, or use Sidekiq or similar enqueue and process jobs at whatever time you want.

### Caveats

Since I have no idea why this is a useful test for you, I won't tell you not to test this way. However, I suspect that you have some time-sensitive edge case that you want to handle. It's generally better to stub/mock whatever method is time sensitive rather than waiting for long periods of time, or adjusting the actual system clock of your web server, so that your tests can only be performed close to midnight.

Tight coupling to external conditions is *usually* a code smell. Consider whether you truly need to test this way before committing to an X/Y solution, because this type of approach often leads to slow tests or "Heisenbugs." Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

You're making it too hard. Simply figure out how many seconds remain until midnight, then `sleep`.

I've used something like this in the past:

```
require 'date'

def seconds_until_midnight
  Date.today.next_day.to_time.to_i - Time.now.to_i
end
```

Testing it:

```
5.times do
  puts '%i seconds until midnight' % seconds_until_midnight()
  sleep 1
end

# >> 35142 seconds until midnight
# >> 35141 seconds until midnight
# >> 35140 seconds until midnight
# >> 35139 seconds until midnight
# >> 35138 seconds until midnight
```

Simply use:

```
sleep seconds_until_midnight()
```

or change the code to:

```
require 'date'

def sleep_until_midnight
  midnight = Date.today.next_day.to_time.to_i - Time.now.to_i
  sleep midnight
end
```

and call `sleep_until_midnight()`.

The is the magical part:

```
Date.today                  # => #<Date: 2020-04-09 ((2458949j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.today.next_day         # => #<Date: 2020-04-10 ((2458950j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.today.next_day.to_time # => 2020-04-10 00:00:00 -0700
```

Dates don't contain a time component, so Ruby fudges and adds a "midnight", AKA `00:00:00`, when converting to a Time object.

If you want to reduce or increase the wait time `n` seconds, subtract or add that value to `midnight` and change the method's signature:

```
def sleep_until_midnight(offset)
:
:
  sleep midnight + offset
end
```

and call it like:

```
sleep_until_midnight(-5)
sleep_until_midnight(+1)
```

Though, similar to what Todd Jacobs says in his answer, why? Tests should run immediately, not at a specific time, so you can get results and react to them as you're developing. If it's to test to see if a page exists or to parse it at a specific time use `cron` or something similar.

Comment: Won't what you have now for computing `midnight` be a problem if it currently is the last day of the month? I suggest `midnight = date.next.to_time_to_i`. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: You might be right. I was thinking it'd roll over, but that might be a Perl-ism. Your suggestion is more concise, something that's always good.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this without the distraction of the `utc` argument.

```
require 'date'

def wait_if_almost_midnight(secs_left_to_begin_reporting = 3600)
  time_now = DateTime.now.to_time
  time_at_midnight = time_now.to_date.next.to_time
  secs_to_midnight = time_at_midnight.to_i - time_now.to_i
  puts "#{secs_to_midnight} seconds until midnight"
  secs_left = secs_to_midnight
  if secs_left > secs_left_to_begin_reporting
    sleep_time = secs_left - secs_left_to_begin_reporting
    secs_left -= sleep_time
    puts "I'm off to sleep for #{sleep_time} seconds, then I'll report "
    puts "every second for the last #{secs_left_to_begin_reporting-1} seconds"
    puts "zzzzzzzzzzzz"
    sleep(sleep_time)
  end
  (secs_left-1).downto(1) do |i|
    p "Waiting for midnight, seconds waited so far: #{secs_to_midnight-i}"
    sleep(1)
  end
end
```

Let's try it:

```
wait_if_almost_midnight(10)
# 37965 seconds until midnight
# I'm off to sleep for 37779 seconds, then I'll report 
# every second for the last 9 seconds
# zzzzzzzzzzzz
```

(later...)

```
# "Waiting for midnight, seconds waited so far: 37780"
# "Waiting for midnight, seconds waited so far: 37781"
# "Waiting for midnight, seconds waited so far: 37782"
# "Waiting for midnight, seconds waited so far: 37783"
# "Waiting for midnight, seconds waited so far: 37784"
# "Waiting for midnight, seconds waited so far: 37785"
# "Waiting for midnight, seconds waited so far: 37786"
# "Waiting for midnight, seconds waited so far: 37787"
# "Waiting for midnight, seconds waited so far: 37788"
```